# nest.js error when deploying start:prod to Digital Ocean App Platform

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, nest

I have been trying to deploy my app to DO and I keep getting the error

```
Error: Cannot find module '/workspace/dist/main'
 at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:15)
 at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)
 at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
 at node:internal/main/run_main_module:22:47 {
 code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
 requireStack: []
 }
```

So I have tried different variations in the package.json within the start:prod command but cant get it to build complete

```
/
/dist/main
../dist/main
```

Does anyone have any experience with getting this to work?

Comment: Are you certain when you build you have `dist/main` and not something like `dist/src/main`?

Comment: Well that worked! Thank you - onto the next problem now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`start:prod` sounds like it should be set to `node dist/src/main`. This usually is the case when there is a file from outside of `src` being compiled *with* `src`, and Typescript is maintaining the directory structure in the output directory.